# pagination are not working?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, pagination

index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            course = $("#courses").val();
            field2 = $("#field2").val();
            $("#imagen").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "courses": course,
                    "field2": field2
                },
                url: "all_college.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#imagen").hide();
                    $("#popular_colleges").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<img id="imagen" src="images/please.gif">
<div id="popular_colleges"></div>
```

all_college.php

```
<?php
    $course = $_POST['courses'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];

    $per_page=10;
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) 
    {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
    }
    else 
    {
        $page=1;
    }
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

    $sql = "select * from all_colleges where courses like '%,$course,%' LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
        <?php echo $row['college_name']; ?>
        <?php echo $row['address']; ?>
<?php
    }
?>

<?php
    $query = "select * from all_colleges";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
    echo "<center><a href='index.php?page=1' style='padding:10px;'>".'First Page'."</a>";
    $skipped = false;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)  {
        if ($i < 3 || $total_pages- $i < 3 || abs($page - $i) < 3) {
            if ($skipped)
                echo '<span> ... </span>';
            $skipped = false;
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=" . $i . "' style='padding:5px;'>" . $i . "</a>";
        } else {
            $skipped = true;
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages' style='padding:10px;'>".'Last Page'."</a></center>";
?>
```

In this code when I click on submit button it will show data upto 10 result as I define $per_page = 10 and pagination number are showing as well but when I click any number of pagination suppose I click 2 then index page reload and data will not display. So, how can I fix this problem ? Please help.

Thank You

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: pagination only works if you have an order by clause

Comment: @kevin I thought it might help to clarify Jen's comment about ORDER BY and Pagination -- by default, SQL does NOT guarantee any kind of row ordering at all. Even though it "usually" returns rows by row-number, it could change execution patterns and not at any time. ORDER BY classes are *the* way to order rows, and Jen's saying paginating records makes no sense if they're in no particular order. Although fwiw, you could also paginate and order on the frontend in your jQuery. But you would want to do either both in script or add an ordering clause.